# Is it a good practice to write two letters vertically in a word for a logo design?

Tags: website-design, logo, design-principles

I'm making a logo for a noun. Now, the word has 2 adjacent letters in it that can make a thing that describes the noun. But for that I have to put them in vertical order. For example, consider the word **Example** (Here it reveals nothing but I'm just giving an example):

**E X A M P L E** becomes

[image]

Would it look weird as a word's letters should always be in a particular direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vikas,

Yes there is some "rules" that is better to respect to create balance in our designs but the beauty in what we do is that we are only limited by our own creativity.

One rule I learned a long time ago is... THINK OUTSIDE THE BOX! And that's what you just did.

If the fact that you are placing those 2 letters on top of each other will add meaning to the logo, make it stand out, well, go ahead and do it!

Hope this helps!

Pat

Comment: Yes it's weird without a reason.

Comment: Once you're done, why not posting your final design here?